# Replace char in string with uppercase char

Tags: c++, string

i was wondering how i could go about fixing my issue that my specified char in my string won't be uppercased. If anyone can help that would be awesome :)

What im trying to get the results of:

```
std::cout << "Non converted: hello world!" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Converted: Hello world!" << std::endl;
```

Code

```
std::string text = "hello world!";
std::toupper(text.at(0));
```

This above doesn't work. The return value of std::toupper is an int.
I've also tried:

```
std::string text = "hello world!";
text.replace(text.at(0), std::to_string(std::toupper(text.at(0))));
```

but that wouldn't work either as it just gives a number back as a string and thats not what im looking for. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `toupper` *returns* the value, so you need to assign to `text[0]`.

Comment: Show a [mre] and everything will be solved.

Comment: A warning about something that you don't run into very often (but when you do it's a real brainsmurf) `toupper` takes an `int`, not a `char`. This allows it to handle out-of-band information like EOF, but can result in really weird behaviour. See [this documentation's **Notes** for details and a solution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper#notes).

Comment: "_brainsmurf_" - Added to unordered map.

Answer (score 2):

Any `char` can be converted to an `int`, hence the parameter as an `int` and the return type. It actually does work, but you don't do anything with the return value.

```
text.at(0) = std::toupper(text.at(0));
```

Or:

```
text[0] = std::toupper(text.at(0));
```

Or from your second try:

```
text.replace(text.at(0), std::toupper(text.at(0)));
```

**Note:** DO NOT GIVE `std::toupper()` A RAW `int`! Quoting from the comments:

> A warning about something that you don't run into very often (but when you do it's a real brainsmurf) toupper takes an int, not a char. This allows it to handle out-of-band information like EOF, but can result in really weird behaviour. [See this documentation's **Notes** for details and a solution.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper#notes) – user4581301

Answer (score 2):

`std::toupper()` return an integer value, as you mentioned. You can see this by printing the value:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string text = "hello world!";
    std::cout << (char) std::toupper(text.at(0));
}
```

Result: `H`

So, to assign it:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string text = "hello world!";
    text[0] =  std::toupper(text.at(0));
    std::cout << text;
}
```

Result: `Hello world!`

And as @user4581301 mentioned, feeding `int`s into `toupper()` can have some consequences.

For your second case, as mentioned, feeding `to_string()` a character will not output what you want:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    char c = std::toupper('c'); 
    std::cout << c << "\n";
    std::cout << std::to_string(c);
}
```

Result:

```
C
67
```

A (rather hacky) workaround:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    std::string text = "hello world!";
    std::string tmp = ""; tmp += std::toupper(text[0]);
    text.replace(0, 1, tmp);
    std::cout << text;
}
```

Result: `Hello world!`

More info:

- `replace()`: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/
- `toupper()` and notes: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper#notes
- `to_string()` : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string